# Get values from TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, textbox

I have two functions. In my first i have created the TextBox:

```
private TableRow GetGebuchteDienstleistungRow(Dienstleistungsreservierung dr, int rowIndex)
{

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();

    if (dr.Dienstleistung.Mengeneinheit == Mengeneinheit.Basket)
    {
        foreach (Basketdienstleistung basketDl in dr.Dienstleistung.Basket)
        {
            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "<tr />";
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            TableRenderer.AddTableCell(row, dr.Von.ToString(form.DatumsFormat), 1);
            TableRenderer.AddTableCell(row, dr.Von.ToString(form.ZeitFormat), 1);
            TableRenderer.AddTableCell(row, dr.Bis.ToString(form.DatumsFormat), 1);
            TableRenderer.AddTableCell(row, dr.Bis.ToString(form.ZeitFormat), 1);

            cell = new TableCell();
            var txt = new TextBox();   
            txt.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dr.Bestellmenge * basketDl.Anzahl);
            txt.Width = 42;
            txt.MaxLength = 5;
            txt.CssClass = "nummer";
            cell.Controls.Add(txt);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);


            ................

            }


        }

    }
    .................
```

How can i get the value of the created TextBox in my second function? Specifically I want to pass the value in a database.

Comment: You can assign ID to the textbox.
var txt= new TextBox{ ID="MyTextBox"}(); Then in your second function you can get textbox value from the textbox id. MyTextBox.Text

Comment: After the post back, or now as they are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FindControl method`

```
var textBox = (TextBox)cell.FindControl("YourID");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate through all controls in specific cell and find your textbox by name

```
cell.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```